# Hot to fix the edit function on React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried this :
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-fire-2639k

When I click the edit button, I can put the text to input fields and edit, and after I press submit, the text added to list as a new one. But I want only to edit it, not to add again as a new one. How can I fix?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the relevant code, a description of the issue, any debugging & reproduction steps, and what the actual and expected behaviors are and should be. Links out to external resources are OK supplemental resources, but the code with issue should be included as a properly formatted code snippet here in your question so it since links tend to decay over time.

Comment: Seems you may just be missing an "editMode" in state to know whether or not to add a new entry, or to simply update an existing on already in state. That or you can simply remove it from the `posts` array and let the submit reinsert it.

Comment: I have put the link of "codes and box" for a better view of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ouptut:**

[image]

Here is another example, where the id's are dynamically generated so as to avoid using index, title, content for filtering purpose, it allows to edit the title as well as contents of the posts too.

here are how to edit, delete and update functionality works underneath:

```js
// delete function
deleteItem(id) {
    //console.log(textarea);
    const filteredItems = this.state.posts.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    this.setState({
      posts: filteredItems
    });
  }

// function to get posts to be edited
  editPost(id) {
    const filterPosts = this.state.posts.filter((item) => item.id === id);
    console.log(filterPosts);
    this.setState({
      form: filterPosts[0]
    });
  }

// add new and edit existing posts

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.posts);
    let updateFlag = false;
    let updatedPosts = this.state.posts.map((post) => {
      if (post.id === this.state.form.id) {
        updateFlag = true;
        return {
          title: this.state.form.title,
          textarea: this.state.form.textarea,
          id: post.id
        };
      }
      return post;
    });

    if (!updateFlag) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          posts: [
            {
              ...prevState.form,
              ...{ id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) }
            },
            ...prevState.posts
          ],
          form: {
            title: "",
            textarea: ""
          }
        };
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          posts: updatedPosts,
          form: {
            title: "",
            textarea: ""
          }
        };
      });
    }
  }
```

[image: Edit hot-to-fix-the-edit-function-on-react-js]

Comment: thank you! another great solution! after this, if i want that every time a create e new post,  the date when the post created to be in the content. can you show me hint how to do that?

Comment: if you want to associate the date with each post then you can simply add it using ```new Date()```

Comment: added it here, byt doesnt work right, https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-fire-2639k

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-joliot-ox1wz?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: don't forget to wrap date ```JSON.stringify(new Date())```

Answer (score 0):

You could save an 'edit" index to know in the `handleSubmit` whether or not the form data should be prepended to the `posts` array or if it should updated a specific post at an index.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      editIndex: -1, // <-- add an editIndex state
      posts: [],
      form: {
        title: "",
        textarea: ""
      }
    };
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.editItem = this.editItem.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  ...

  // Find a matching post index and if found copy post into form state
  editItem(textarea, title) {
    const postIndex = this.state.posts.findIndex(
      (item) => item.title === title && item.textarea === textarea
    );

    if (postIndex === -1) return;

    this.setState({
      editIndex: postIndex,
      form: {
        ...this.state.posts[postIndex]
      }
    });
  }

  ...

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        editIndex: -1, // <-- reset "edit mode"
        posts:
          prevState.editIndex === -1
             // <-- not editing, prepend form data
            ? [prevState.form, ...prevState.posts]
             // <-- editing, overwite post at index
            : prevState.posts.map((post, index) =>
                index === prevState.editIndex ? { ...prevState.form } : post
              ),
        form: {
          title: "",
          textarea: ""
        }
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

[image: Edit hot-to-fix-the-edit-function-on-react-js]